# A finite group is isomorphic to cyclic group

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Is this true that for a finite group $G$, if there exists an element $a\in G$, $|G|=\text{ord}(a)$, then it is isomorphic to the cyclic group $C_{|G|}$?

Comment: Yes, if you take $\{e, a, a^2,\ldots, a^{ord(a)-1}\}$ then what else is there in $G$?

Comment: That holds by the very definition of cyclic group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true, since $\operatorname{ord}(a)=|G|$ we have that the subgroup generated by $a$ (which is cyclic) is a subgroup of $G$ with order $|G|$, hence equal to $G$.